# "Brown" and other causative color verbs

Tags: etymology, causative-verbs, verb-forms

There are several verbs in English meaning "to cause to become [a given color]". Most of these, it seems, end in the suffix "-en". There are other adjectives as well that use "-en" to create causative verbs; "harden" and "fasten" come to mind.

The verb meaning "to make brown, tthough, is simply "brown". I can't think of any other verb of this class that uses the bare adjective form without a suffix. Does "brown" have a different history than other causative verbs formed from adjectives? Or why did it, and seemingly only it, retain the adjective form?

Comment: Well, one reason is that "brownen" would sound like a mumble.

Comment: I can only think of 'redden' and 'whiten'. 'Brownen' and 'greenen' would sound odd, but we don't say 'bluen' or 'yellowen' either.

Comment: @KateBunting add "blacken"

Comment: [blue, entry 3 of 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blue), verb,  "to make (something) blue in color: such as to dye, tint, or paint (something) blue" just like brown! Fun new word: _of a woman:  learned, intellectual //… the ladies were very blue and well-informed_ …

Comment: @Conrado "[I'm afraid I just blue myself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jw1UN1Iz78)." The joke would be completely ruined if it were "emblue" or "bluen." There may be a weak sound rule here - ends in vowel or [n], no -en; ends in consonant, -en.

Comment: There is also "pinken" (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pinken).

Comment: A similar thing exists with 'embrown' which also means we make something brown in color, but we don't have words like emred, or emblack.

Comment: @LPH perfect, thanks! I didn't find that in my search, I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: Don't forget _enlighten_ vs _lighten_. There are prefixal and suffixal grades.

Comment: How about the verb *yellow*.  "Become yellow, especially with age."